# Prevent divs from overlapping on resize

Tags: css

I have a page I have 3 separate DIV's aligned, one right, center, then left. Which looks perfect when the page is at default size, however on smaller re-sizes they all 3 could rest on top of one another, which makes them unreadable.

My current CSS, all the same except the right value.

```
.Cat_One {
margin-left: 2%;
position:fixed;
left: 170px;

min-width: 20%;
max-width: 20%;
max-height: 350px;
overflow: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
```

}

My body CSS

```
body {
width: 100%;
min-height: 690px;
min-width: 1275px;
margin-left: -0px;
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-x: scroll;
```

}

I just need to figure out a way to stop them from overlapping on resize. Tried many of the similar posts and doesn't seem my case is the same and the suggestions there don't exactly work out.. Perhaps I missed something.

Comment: Can you make a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)? Don't use fixed positioning if the same thing can be accomplished using the normal layout flow.

Comment: This is just not enough code to be able to answer your question

Comment: A note: If `position:fixed; left: 170px;` without a `top`or  `bottom` setting is the CSS for *three* DIVs, they will be above each other on *any* screen. Fixed position is an exception for fixed footers, headers o sidebars, but is definitely not a good choice for content containers.

Answer (score 0):

Without more code, my best guess is the issue is with your position:fixed. Dump that. Depending on what you are looking to do, you can do display:inline-block; or use flexbox, or float:left; or if this is tabular data you could even use a table.

Position fixed though, I would put money on that not being what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (Kinda). What i did was add this into the css:

```
top: 0px;
Right: 0px;
Position: Absolute;
```

This will make the div lock to the upper right corner of the page, and then use:

```
Transform: Translate(XXvw, XXvh);
```

The transform is used to relocate objects to where you want it ^^

You must also specify this in the css for html,body else it won't work:

```
Min-height: 100vh;
Min-width: 100vw; (100% of the viewport/browser window).
```